# Is there a Java equivalent of IConvertible/System.Convert?

Tags: java, .net, converters

Is there a Java equivalent, or a Java library with, a type that does the same thing as `System.Convert` in .NET?

I want a method that takes an `Object` and does whatever it can to convert it into an Integer, Long, String, etc. I can easily write my own, but I would prefer to use one in a library...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think they is no equivalent in JAVA.

But you can test this solution :

```
public String convertString(Object oject1)
{
    if ( oject1 instanceof Integer)
    {
          /// convert method
          return stringConvert
    }
    if ( oject1 instanceof Long)
    {
          /// Convert method
    }
    ......


}
```

Comment: It's much more complicated than that.  You need to do things like convert a boxed `Integer` to `Long`.